# Execute some code after all trigger batches complete?

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext, queueable-interface

Suppose I update 1000 records and I have an `after update` trigger. That trigger will run 5 times for each batch of 200. Is there any possible way to collect data over the course of the 5 executions and then have some code run, only once, on that data after the last batch of 200 is complete?

The only way that's occurred to me is to set up a `Queueable`. In theory I could stash in a static variable the accumulated data that I want to pass to it. Enqueue it once during the first execution and then use a static variable to mark that it's already run. The trouble is that once enqueued, the `Queueable` remembers only the data passed to it and doesn't check for further changes. So with each execution I'd have to abort the previous `Queueable` instance, then re-enqueue it with the new data. But when you queue a job and then abort it, it still counts against limits. So ideally I'd just like it to run only once at the end.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What you're looking for [is this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5BWAAY). Go ahead and vote, I'll wait here.

Comment: I voted! - Where is my sticker :)

Comment: Interesting idea. What I'm describing is slightly different - not to run at the end of the transaction, just after the present execution of the present trigger reaches its last set of records.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is from last year, still hasn't been added. Any ideas how this can be accomplished now?

Comment: @shmuli I'm actually designing a super-trigger framework, but I don't know when it'll be available or even exactly what it'll look like (but will probably be similar to fflib's Unit of Work design); the ultimate goal is to have a consistent interface for bulk updates without dealing with Salesforce's chunking mechanisms.

Comment: So this would be what, a framework to replace a standard DML statement? Unfortunately that still wouldn't help with transactions started directly by API. But I'm curious to see how it turns out.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this.  I know records are batched, but it seems like it's all happening behind the scenes.  The trigger appears to run only once in the logs; the last line of code seems to be executed one time, after all of the other logic is complete.  If this is true, then is it really necessary to collect data over the course of each separate execution in order to act on it all at once after the last batch?

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld If you batch more than 200 records, the trigger code runs once per batch, all in the same Apex transaction. For under 200 you will only see it run once in the log.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesT.  I just ran an update on 1k records, and still only saw one instance in the logs.  Again, I know there is some sort of batching happening, but I'm only seeing the code execute one time.  Sorry to hound you about this, but I'm working on a trigger framework, and I want to be sure I haven't missed something vital!  Much appreciated  :)

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld I don't know what to tell you... the behaviour you are describing goes against what is stated in all the developer documentation and training. Try putting `System.debug('entering trigger code!');` at the top of your trigger. Update 1000 records. Do you really only see the message logged once?

Comment: Aw, crap. @CharlesT, I set my query to LIMIT 1000...but there were only 14 records in my sandbox!  Ugh.  Okay, yes, I inserted 1k records and did see the start and finish debug lines in my code 5 times each.  That makes more sense now.  I'm going to post a related question, probably later today.  I'll ping you with the URL here if you're interested.  I appreciate the help and want to make sure you get some credit for it!  Thanks, Charles.